# How to store statistics in database

Tags: .net, database, database-design, architecture, statistics

I have the following table

```
Restaurant Type, Location, HowMany
-----------------------------------
Chinese, New York, 20
Chinese, London, 40
Indian, New York, 33
Indian, Sydney, 55
```

The numbers in the How Many column change over time, and new rows could also be added to the table.

What I am trying to achieve is some statistics (e.g. monthly or weekly), to show the how the 'HowMany' Column values has changed over time for a particular combination of restaurant type/location.

i was thinking of taking a snapshot of the table every month/week and gathering the statistics that way, but I was hoping there might be a better solution.. any solution that would make it easy for me to display the data in a bar graph.

Is there a way better than storing a blob of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating an historical table with a timestamp that links to the main table with a foreign key.  Create a function that inserts into the historical table with a timestamp and the old value every time the main table is changed.

```
ID, RestaurantType, Location, HowMany
---------------------------------------------------------------
1, Chinese, New York, 20
```

The historical will look like

```
ID, MainTableID, Value, DateChanged
----------------------------------------------------------
1, 1, 18, 8/1/2015
2, 1, 19, 8/5/2015
```

Comment: however the number of rows in the historical table will hange over time?

Comment: It will, the historical table will grow, but you can query to pull all the historical and present data to suit a bar graph easily.  And you would be keeping the actual past records for statistical analysis.

Comment: I see what you mean now - thanks for putting up the table.